# How can I parse date in Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017 format in Java?

Tags: java, date

I have tried the below code to parse the date in `Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017` format. But, it is showing parsing exception. How can I parse the date format for `Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017`?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
Date bbDate=sdf.parse(String.valueOf("Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017"));
System.out.println(bbDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an unhandled exception. You need to surround the parse line in a try-catch, or have the function itself throw an exception.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

    try {
        Date bbDate = sdf.parse("Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017");
        System.out.println(bbDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // … Handle exception.
        System.out.println( "ERROR…" );
    }
```

Here is the documentation to learn more about Java exceptions.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: Please, not even in a code snippet meant to explain something, or maybe particularly not here, *don’t* swallow an exception.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use new Java Date Time api: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html

You can do the same thing with the new api as follows:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy")).toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: Why the call to `toLocalDateTime` at the end? You are discarding valuable time zone information for no reason.

Comment: You are right. I just wanted to show, how to get LocalDateTime instance ZonedDateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Its just not handled Parse Exception. Your SimpleDateFormat is good.

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        Date bbDate;
        bbDate = sdf.parse(String.valueOf("Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017"));
        System.out.println(bbDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Well. I tried even with handling  exceptions. Still no luck.I am still getting the same exception.Does this to do with the java version as I am using Java Version 6(1.6.0.29)?

Comment: yes maybe it is from the java version. try switching to java 7 or java 8

Comment: they changed simpledateformat in java 7 i think

Comment: In My application, We are using java 6 only. So, I need to parse the date in Java 6 format.

Answer (score 0):

Since your string uses English names for week day and month, you need to make sure that your `SimpleDateFormat` uses a locale with English language, for example:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", Locale.ROOT);
```

With this change your code prints (tested with Java 8):

```
Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017
```

EDIT: please fill in the appropriate (English-speaking) locale instead of `Locale.ROOT`.

I agree with Ali Sağlam in warmly recommending the `java.time` classes introduced in Java 8. You will still need to control the locale, though:

```
    ZonedDateTime.parse("Tue Apr 11 00:00:00 CEST 2017",
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                                    Locale.ROOT))
            .toLocalDateTime();
```

Finally, while we’re at the recommendations, see if you can find a way to avoid the three and four letter time zone abbreviations like `CEST`. Many of them are ambiguous, and CEST isn’t even really a full time zone, just the summer half of the Central European time zone. While it works as expected with a date in the summer time half of year, I’m not even sure what I should expect if one day you have a date in winter with `CEST` time zone abbreviation.

Comment: `Locale.ROOT` ??

Comment: Interesting question, @BasilBourque. I am routinely using `Locale.ROOT` to mean something like “the locale neutral locale”. For example, rather than passing a `null` for locale to `String.format()` I prefer to pass `Locale.ROOT` to mean “do not apply any localization”. In this case I was in doubt, but figured that the input String more likely came out of either `Date.toString()` or a corresponding non-locale-dependent source in some other system. If the string is in English because it comes from an English speaking locality, one should of course use the corresponding locale, not `ROOT`.